# Mounting is slow after 4000 mounts

Tags: mount, kernel, bind-mount

I have a need to create about 10,000 total bind mounts for various chroots. After about 3000-4000 mounts, it slows down significantly from 100/s to about 5-10/s. I'm assuming it's hitting some weird internal limit for perhaps allocations in the kernel, and the kernel is having to expand them for each mount. Is there a known sysctl setting to bump this up ahead of time?

Comment: Just a thought. Are you using namespaces? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html

Comment: @PhilipCouling I am pretty naive in this, sadly. I'm literally just running this in a set up script: `mount --bind /my/chroot/bin /chroots/number1/bin` and then remounting as ro with `mount -o remount,ro $chroot/bin`. So, if you have a better suggestion, I'd be very happy to hear it!

Comment: @PhilipCouling will consider that possibility, I'm working on a relatively older kernel (centos6, a limitation I'm already dealing with poorly as it is). Will have to figure out what is introdued when.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Actually, thinking about it, it looks like it could be `/etc/mtab` that is causing problems for me. But the problem is that I can't just symlink this to `/proc/mounts` because then re-mounting RO doesn't work. I wonder what workaround I could do there. Potentially has to do with parsing the massive file?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking along the lines of namespaces it might be possible for you to reduce the number of mounts required.  You're using these for chroot environments so I guess you're making several mounts per environment.

You might be able to get that much lower by creating one template environment and mounting apps into it inside their own namespace.

[Wikipedia Linux Namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces):

> The Linux Namespaces originated in 2002 in the 2.4.19 kernel

Inside a name space you can create mounts which are not shared by other processes.  So you can start a new namespace, bind mount one single app into your chroot environment and then chroot into it.  No other app will be able to see that last mount.

Let's say you know that every environment is going to need `/etc` `/dev` `/proc` `/sys` `/tmp` `/bin`.  You could create a template `/chroot_env`:

```
# bind mount
/chroot_env
/chroot_env/etc
/chroot_env/dev
/chroot_env/proc
/chroot_env/sys
/chroot_env/tmp
/chroot_env/bin
# With empty directories
/chroot_env/opt
/chroot_env/opt/app
```

Then before you actually call `chroot` you can:

```
# Start a new shell in a new namespace
unshare --mount
mount --bind /opt/my_app /chroot_env/opt/app

# run the app as a chroot
chroot /chroot_env /opt/my_app
```

Note that to do this in a script you might need to do something like:

```
unshare --mount sh -c 'mount --bind /opt/my_app /chroot_env/opt/app && chroot /chroot_env /opt/my_app/run'
```

This means you are just making one mount per app (to `/opt/app`) rather than one per environment instead of 6(?).